# RADIUS calculating the Message-Authenticator

Tags: c#

I 'd like to know , how to calculate and compare the value of the Message - Authenticator under radius server
- Type of what?
- Identify what?
- Length of what?
- Attributes of what?

Answer (score 0):

Type, one of:

```
Access-Request = 1
Access-Accept = 2
Access-Reject = 3
Access-Challenge = 11
```

Identity:

```
For Access-Request, a random number between 0 and 255
Otherwise the identity from the Access-Request
```

Length

```
Total length of the packet being sent = 20 + len(attrs)
```

Attributes

```
A Key:Value list of attributes [1] being sent.
```

[1] https://www.iana.org/assignments/radius-types/radius-types.txt